# python on win32: how to get absolute timing / CPU cycle-count

Tags: python, winapi, api, performancecounter

I have a python script that calls a USB-based data-acquisition C# dotnet executable. The main python script does many other things, e.g. it controls a stepper motor.  We would like to check the relative timing of various operations, for that purpose the dotnet exe generates a log with timestamps from C# Stopwatch.GetTimestamp(), which as far as I know yields the same number as calls to win32 API QueryPerformanceCounter().

Now I would like to get similar numbers from the python script.  time.clock() returns such values, unfortunately it subtracts the value obtained at the time of 1st call to time.clock().  How can I get around this?  Is it easy to call QueryPerformanceCounter() from some existing python module or do I have to write my own python extension in C?

I forgot to mention, the python WMI module by Tim Golden does this:
wmi.WMI().Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_System()[0].Timestamp_PerfTime
, but it is too slow, some 48ms overhead. I need something with <=1ms overhead.  time.clock() seems to be fast enough, as is c# Stopwatch.GetTimestamp().

TIA,
Radim

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried using ctypes?

```
from ctypes import *
val = c_int64()
windll.Kernel32.QueryPerformanceCounter(byref(val))
print val.value
```

Comment: Works well, I am able to get readouts about 0.5ms apart (vs. 48ms with WMI).  Thank you, Luc.

Comment: Here's an extension of the above, with micros(), millis(), delay(), and delayMicroseconds() functions for Python in Windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38319606/how-to-get-millisecond-and-microsecond-resolution-timestamps-in-python. Thanks @luc for providing the syntax of accessing QueryPerformanceCounter in Python!

Comment: @luc, should you be using `val = c_uint64()` instead of `val = c_int64()`?

Comment: or maybe not??? Since this (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383713(v=vs.85).aspx) shows the "QuadPart" being a signed 64-bit integer.

Answer (score 0):

You could just call the C# `StopWatch` class directly from Python couldn't you?  Maybe a small wrapper is needed (don't know Python/C# interop details - sorry) - if you are already using C# for data acquisition, doing the same for timings via `Stopwatch` should be simpler than anything else you can do.