# Assign ProcessPoolExecutor to defined cpus and using queues to communicate

Tags: python, queue, raspberry-pi3, concurrent.futures, high-resolution-time

hope you guys can help me.
I searched a lot but was not able to find a solution for my problem.

I am using a Raspberry 3 B+ to communicate to a safety plc with a constant cycle time of 2ms.
To satisfy my needs I used the Preempt-RT Patch for the Linux Kernel and worked with an accurate microsecond timing of this link:

[How to get millisecond and microsecond-resolution timestamps in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38319606/)

With isolcpus and the taskset command I isolated two cpus for my pyhton script to avoid longer cycle times caused by the operating system.
Receiving and sending some bits via the GPIOs of the Raspberry with a 2ms cycle time is my first task and works fine now.

The second task is to read and write the information to a MySQL database, which is not time critical (the database connection works fine already).
I therefore thought of using a queue which could be the connection between my fast task and the slow database-task.

However, here is my problem.
If I use Concurrent Future ThreadPoolExecutor, I can easily use a queue but by 2ms time is, as expected, completely destroyed.
Therefore I thought of using the ProcessPoolExecutor to use both isolated cpus and splitting the two tasks to one cpu each.
But there are two questions I cannot solve:

1. I want to assign the fast task to one cpu and the slow task to the second cpu (both cpus are isolated). How can I accomplish that?
2. I need two queues (Transmit, Receive) to communicate. I was not able to find a way to communicate between two processes in both directions.

I also thought of using two different scripts that i can add to a cpu independently, but here is again the problem of communicating between those scripts.

Is there a way to solve this problem?
By the way, I am completely new to python and hope I am able to understand your ideas. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If someone has the same problem in the future: I solved the problem with the use of ZeroMQ to communicate between two independent scripts. I set up a bidirectional communication with Publish/Subscribe Messaging Pattern.
See: https://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/pubsub.html